# How can I make Jackson not treat my class as a Map?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using Jackson to serialize a custom class that implements `Map<String, String>`.  But behind the scenes, it's actually a `Map<String, String[]>` (this class represents HTTP request parameters), and I'd like for Jackson to serialize it as if it's a `Map<String, String[]>`.  I had thought that the [JsonValue](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonValue.html) annotation would be perfect for this (I'd annotate a method that returns the inner `Map<String, String[]>`), but it Jackson seems to be ignoring it.  How can I disable Map-style treatment of this class, and have it be serialized either as  POJO or via the `JsonValue` annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best choice is a custom serializer/deserializer, since there is no way for Jackson to know that your Map is "faking it" (i.e. its signature is wrong).

But if `@JsonValue` does not work, that sounds like a bug.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't looked at the code, but my assumption is that the `@JsonValue` check only happens once Jackson has decided that the class is bean-like, and not collection-like.  I've gotten `@JsonValue` to work correctly in other contexts, but when the class appears to be collection-like, I think it gets ignored.

Comment: Right, this is correct assumption at high-level. But code should ideally check for @JsonValue annotation, as it will be available: this is handled for Enums for sure. So I'll see if this can be made to work for Maps and Collections as well.

Comment: For what it is worth, this has been fixed for Jackson 2.0.0, so that @JsonValue should finally work for all types (including Map and Collection types).